# How to create a simple java kafka consumer and connect to a topic using kerberos authentication?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect a kafka topic present in higher environment from my local java kafka client using kerberos authentication,My client code is like below :

```
String bootstrapServers = "bootstrap server details";
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 600000);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
        org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
        org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-group-id");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");

properties.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
properties.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name", "esaas");
properties.put("sasl.mechanism", "GSSAPI");

String keyTabPath = "D:/Kerberos/myKeyTab.keytab";
String principal = "abc@def.com";
properties.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG,
                "com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required " + "useTicketCache=false " + "useKeyTab=true "
                        + "serviceName=esaas " + "debug=true " + "keyTab=\"" + keyTabPath + "\"" + "principal=\""
                        + principal + "\";");

KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("my-topic"));

try {
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));

                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    System.out.println("Key: " + record.key() + ", Value: " + record.value());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

when i ran this code it is not throwing any exception but i am not getting response also just getting below log:

Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded

What i am missing here ?

Comment: And why would one add Spring-related tag if there is nothing in the question about Spring?..